# Python code to print a number's 10 times tables

Tags: python

I am really new to python and have not been doing it long. I have tried running this code but it won't work- 'Invalid Syntax' comes up each time. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Thanks.

```
n=int(input('Enter a number to view it\'s 10 times tables:'))
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 1 =' n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 2 =' 2*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 3 =' 3*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 4 =' 4*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 5 =' 5*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 6 =' 6*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 7 =' 7*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 8 =' 8*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 9 =' 9*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 10 =' 10*n)
```

Comment: You want a comma in your print statements. `print('x 9 =' 9*n)` should be `print('x 9 =', 9*n)` for example. Also it would be much more programming like to loop this.

Comment: You could have easily narrowed this down to one line instead of just posting everything you had.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `SyntaxError` in each print statement. You want to print multiple items, so add a comma between each item when using `print`:

```
n=int(input('Enter a number to view it\'s 10 times tables:'))
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 1 =', n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 2 =', 2*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 3 =', 3*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 4 =', 4*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 5 =', 5*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 6 =', 6*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 7 =', 7*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 8 =', 8*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 9 =', 9*n)
print(n, end=' ')
print('x 10 =', 10*n)
```

However, when you want to do something N times, you can use a loop:

```
n=int(input('Enter a number to view it\'s 10 times tables:'))
for multiple in range(1, 11):
    print(n, end = ' ')
    print('x', multiple, '=', multiple * n)
```

You can also use string formatting to make this much nicer to work with:

```
n=int(input('Enter a number to view it\'s 10 times tables:'))
for multiple in range(1, 11):
    print('{a} x {b} = {result}'.format(a = n, b = multiple, result = n * multiple))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number to view it's 10 times tables:"))
for x in range(11):
    print("{} x {} = {}".format(n, x, n*x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check up on [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) in Python. The `print` statement (or function in Python 3) will print properly formatted strings. But as is, your strings are not properly formatted and hence not *printable*, and will raise a SyntaxError.

You should do:

```
print 'x 1 = %d'%n
```

Or:

```
print('x 1 = {}'.format(n))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "properly formatted"? The print function can represent *any* object, that's its point in comparison directly writing to streams. If it's a string, it's appropriate for `print`. If the syntax is wrong as in the opening post (`"foo" 2`) then it's not an object at all.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If you intend to print strings, not objects in general. Besides how would print an object without its  `__str__` or `__repr__` method?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Every object has a `__repr__` method, even if it's just the one inherited from `object`. It creates the id string, e.g. `<object at 0x10664a170>`. Thus, every object is printable. A SyntaxError is thrown on an entirely different level, regardless of whether `print` is involved or not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In this wise, I would consider you right.